# Python Dataframe Explode Rows with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I am sorry to replicate the same question which was answered before but they don't seem to give me the desired outcome, maybe I missed something.

I have a subset of the Stack Overflow dataset like the following:

```
**tags                          time**
c#,winforms                     35
html,css,internet-explorer-7    855
c#,conversion,j#                472
c#,datetime                     556
c#,.net,datetime,timespan       1
php,security                    3
mysql                           5
codeigniter,routes              4
c#,progressbar                  4
.net,ide,linux,mono             2
```

And I want the output like following:

```
**tags                  time**
c#                      35
winforms                35
html                    855
css                     855
internet-explorer-7     855
c#                      472
conversion              472
j#                      472
c#                      556
datetime                556
c#                      1
.net                    1
datetime                1
timespan                1
php                     3
security                3
mysql                   5
codeigniter             4
routes                  4
c#                      4
progressbar             4
.net                    2
ide                     2
linux                   2
mono                    2
```

I have tried the following methods:

- Option-1:

```py
df.explode('tags')
```

- Option-2:

```py
df.set_index(['time']).tags.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(name = 'tags').drop('level_1', axis = 1)
```

In both cases, I get the output the same as my dataframe without exploding.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: I kindly suggest you avoid editing your question and let some experts do the rest.

Comment: Explode only works for list-link columns. You'll need to split the comma separated strings into a list first then explode. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122617/15497888) for a full breakdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From pandas docs [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

> specify a non-empty list with each element be str or tuple

To use explode your 'tags' column needs to be a list type. Apply a function to convert your string tags separated by commas to a list then go with option 1 `df.explode('tags')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Stefan. This was the problem. I have converted the strings into list and explode method worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, from the first version of your question(which was not edited), I guess what you need is a loop over rows using `iterrows`. What I came up with is what following (To keep this answer from becoming lengthy, I just copied a part of your dataframe):

```py
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"tags": ["#c,windoforms,css", "#c,datetime"], "time":[35,40]})
newTags = []
newTime = []
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
  for name in row["tags"].split(","):
    newTags.append(name)
    newTime.append(row["time"])
resultDataframe = pd.DataFrame({"tags": newTags, "time":newTime})
resultDataframe
```

##### Output

```
|    | tags       |   time |
|---:|:-----------|-------:|
|  0 | #c         |     35 |
|  1 | windoforms |     35 |
|  2 | css        |     35 |
|  3 | #c         |     40 |
|  4 | datetime   |     40 |
```

Comment: Hi Amirhossein Kiani, Thank you very much, it worked well. But I found the DataFrame.explode() method to be producing faster result after fixing the string list format issue as mentioned by  @Stefan below.